# Proving Steiner triple system

Tags: combinatorial-designs

Let $S$ be a set of size $v$ and let $T$ be a set of $3$-element subsets of $S$. Furthermore, suppose that

(a) each pair of distinct elements of $S$ belongs to at least one triple in $T$,

(b) $|T| \leq  \dfrac{v(v-1)}{6}$.

Show that $(S, T)$ is a Steiner triple system.

Comment: So far I know there is a min. of (v(v-1))/2 pairs in S in at least one triple in T because it's v choose 2. And I know there's at most (v(v-1))/6 pairs in S. I know that (v(v-1))/6 is the exact amount of pairs needed to have a triple system. My problem is setting up this proof. I know what is required for a Steiner triple system. This is just the first question in the book and it has me stumped. Thanks for responding. I really appericate it!!

Answer (score 1):

Assume the contrary and make a list $L$ as follows: For every pair write down the triple with which it is associated. Then $|L|>\tbinom{v}{2}$ as there exists a pair with two triples. Now since each triple is counted by exactly three pairs so $|T|=|L|/3>\frac{\tbinom{v}{2}}{3}$, a contradiction.